# Javascript reading data from cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

My server is caching cookies and the format is like value1abc&value2cde etc. I have written a function to get the cookies as

```
getData:function (target_url) {
      var jqXHR = $.ajax({
              url:target_url,
              type: "Get",
              async: false,
              success: function (data) {
                   return data
              }
              ,
              error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
              if(jqXHR.status == 404 || errorThrown == 'Not Found') 
              { 
              jqXHR.responseText="There was a 404 error";


             }
            }
           });
```

I am calling this method like

```
var result=this.getData("www.xxx.com");

         alert(result);
```

But i am getting nothing. While when i create a sample test page on my local server with values value1abc&value2cde and change link to `var result=this.getData(test2.html");` then it works fine and i get the result. But when i replace with the my server page which is actually storing these cookies then i get null value. Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong?

Comment: This question has nothing to do it ``cookie access from JavaScript`` but to get some data over ``XHR``. Please update the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I have comprehended the question well, then you are trying to read the `cookies` set by the `response header`.

If so, you can access the cookies using `document.cookie`.

`document.cookie` will return `'; '` `(semi colon followed by space)` delimited string for all the cookies.

For example, if `example.com` has set the following `cookies`

```
a='123'
b='456'
c='789'
```

`document.cookie` will return `a=1234; b=456; c=789`

Then, you and `split` the value of `document.cookie` with `split('; ')` to get the array of cookies `['a=1234', 'b=456', 'c=789']`

Let's consider the following code

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
cookies.forEach(function(cookie){
    var cookie = cookie.split('=');
    // print them to console
    console.log('key : ' + cookie[0] + ' value : ' + cookie[1]);
    // or use as per the need
});
```

Comment: no actually i am fine with spliting string values but my problem is i am not getting any values. i am using getData() which works for same domain i think and i am using it for cross domain so that is why i am getting null values so any method similar to getData() to get cross domain values? @sarbbottam

Comment: Where is ``getData()``?

Comment: In the above comment you are invoking the function but where is this ``getData`` defined?

Comment: getData is a javascript function

Comment: my bad @sarbottam can you check my question again i have updated everything

Answer (score 0):

You can get cookies from the client directly witout having to ask the server via ajax

you can use document.cookie but you can also use a simple library [like this one](https://github.com/khaliid/Happy-Cookies)

You can then access to cookies like this :

```
var Cookie = $.getCookie("key");
```

Comment: thanks but my requirement is to hit the url which returns cookies as value1&value2=cde etc and then show on the html5 template